# How can determine if FlowCollector is closed?

Tags: kotlin, timer, reactive-programming, kotlin-coroutines, cancellation

Please check code below, which represents periodical flow.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.time.delay

fun Duration.asFlow(): Flow<Unit> {
    val delayTime = this

    return flow {
        do {
            emit(Unit)

            delay(delayTime)
        } while (true)
    }
}
```

**Question:** can I rely, that function under `flow` will be cancelled when flow is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flow will be cancelled if one of the downstream operators cancel it. If the operator tries to consume the entire flow, it won't complete without intervention.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I checked this. However, is it just current behavior (which can be changed) or it is public contract? Also: do I get any exceptions during the closed ```emit``` calling?

Comment: `emit` will throw `CancellationException` (be careful when catching it), assuming `delay` doesn't throw it.

Comment: This is a public contract.

Comment: Where can I find this? There is nothing at the official documentation - https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow-collector/emit.html

Comment: It's more of an implied thing, related to how cancellation works in coroutines in general. https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/first.html